# R generate bi- and trigrams from column

Tags: regex, r

I have a column containing a word in each row:

```
 word
 -----
 asdf
 wer
 asdf
```

Is there a way to get the most frequent bi- and trigrams over all rows?
For instance for bigrams:

```
aa: 10%
ab: 9%
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with this particular sort of problem, but a little Google work turned up the `tau` package for "N-Gram Based Text Categorization". And using the `textcnt` function on your sample looked like this:

```
x <- c('asdf','wer','asdf')
textcnt(x,3)
```

and seems to return the sort of information you're looking for.